# Is it possible to split a xslt file into multiples file?

Tags: xslt, xsl-fo

I have a *(currently)* 3000 lines XSLT file,  containing a bunch of templates. I have to add even more *stuff* to it and it's becoming pretty much unmanageable.

So could I split it and add includes of some sort?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's what `xsl:import` is there for. (Note that it is not a simple textual file include, though.)

Comment: I'm gonna accept this answer since it mades me find what I used : `xsl:include`.

Answer (score 0):

"Refactoring" is it what you need, I believe, not just splitting and importing. 
At any moment refactoring takes twice as much time as you think it will.

Comment: Please tell me how I could refactor a xsd that format an xml with over 1500 __differents__ fields to take less than 3000 lines of code.

Answer (score 0):

You could create the new stuff you need to add in a separate XSL file and use `xsl:include` to give the templates, variables & params the same priority/precedence as in the main file. You could also then go on to refactor the existing templates into a few more manageable files and use `xsl:include`.

There is also `xsl:import`, which is similar to `xsl:include`, but gives the included files' templates, params, etc., a lower precendence than those in the xsl file including them.

If you use `xsl:import`, make sure this is what you mean to do, as any variables/params in the imported transform will be overridden by any of the same name defined in the main xsl file.